# Duplicate Meta Description on Salesforce Experience Cloud

Tags: metadata, community-builder, digital-experience, seo

We developed a website in Salesforce Community Cloud and i know that Salesforce creates a SEO-friendly version of the site when a spider or googlebot crawls it.

Using https://search.google.com/test/rich-results and checking the source, i can see that there are two Meta Description. (see screenshots)

### Desciption 1:

[image]

### Description 2:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone have encountered this or have any resolution?  Thank you.